# How can I handle job offers when I'm on a student visa?

Tags: job-search, australia, visa

I've been living about six months abroad on a student visa.

Currently, I am receiving many offers to work here, but I'm always blocked because my visa limitations.

How could I approach the headhunters with the situation with regarding my visa?

Comment: Where are you located? What is your citizenship?

Comment: This strongly depends on the country you're in.

Comment: @さりげない告白 He's tagged it Australia, so he's presumably talking about the restrictions on student visas in Australia.

Comment: Tough luck, the student visa was designed for students and not meant to allow you to work... I believe you get 20 hours a week, and if you want to work longer it needs to be off the books. Even after you finish your studies and switch to a work visa, it can be pretty tough since a lot of jobs (for grads) only accept residents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many employers can **sponsor work visas**, so just ask the headhunters if this is an option.  However, you'll need to finish up your studies first.

Depending on the country you're in, it may be possible to legally work while you study, but this typically comes with tight limits on how many hours per week you can work and what kind of work you can do, meaning this is usually only an option for part-time retail jobs or similar.

Comment: That's the point, I received about 25 offers and for all then was impossible sponsor visa, I don't know if is exclusively here in Australia, nut is pretty hard to deal about visa's stuff in this country.

Comment: Getting work visas in Australia is tougher than it used to be, but there are definitely employers out there who can sponsor then.  If you've gotten 25 offers, you're obviously in demand, so keep looking!

Answer (score 2):

Put your visa restrictions on your CV, linked-in page or whatever the recruiters are using to find you.

If you're not sure, ask the next one where they would have expected to see it. They don't want to waste their own time on a candidate that isn't allowed to take the job.